# Export DAO.recordset from Access to Excel produces blank columns in datatype int columns

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, export-to-excel, dao

Using the built-in DAO functions in Access to export to Excel, but if the datatype in the Access table column is set to int, the column will be blank in Excel. If I set the data type to short text before running the function, the data will export correctly. What's going on here?

This is my export function:

```
Private Sub export_Click()
        If IsNull(DLookup("Name", "MSysObjects", "Name='tbl_final_output'")) Then
                MsgBox ("Ingen fundne spilletider til eksport.")
        Else

    Dim sortChoice As Integer

    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsLabel As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsData As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim lngLoop1 As Long
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim faneblad As String
    Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)

    sortChoice = Me.sortBox.Value

    Select Case sortChoice

    Case 1
        faneblad = "Track-ID"
    Case 2
        faneblad = "Gramex-ID"
    Case 3
        faneblad = "Producer No_"
    Case 4
        faneblad = "Label no_"
    Case 5
        faneblad = "Organization No_"
    End Select

    strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT [" & faneblad & "] FROM tbl_final_output ORDER BY [" & faneblad & "] ASC;"
    Set rsLabel = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    If Not (rsLabel.BOF And rsLabel.EOF) Then
        Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
        Do
            Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets.Add(After:=xlBook.Worksheets(xlBook.Worksheets.Count))
            xlSheet.Name = rsLabel(faneblad)
            strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_final_output WHERE [" & faneblad & "]=" & "'" & rsLabel(faneblad) & "'"
            Set rsData = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
            For cols = 0 To rsData.Fields.Count - 1
                xlSheet.Cells(1, cols + 1).Value = rsData.Fields(cols).Name
            Next
            If Not (rsData.BOF And rsData.EOF) Then
                xlSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rsData
            End If
            rsLabel.MoveNext
        Loop Until rsLabel.EOF
        lngCount = xlBook.Worksheets.Count
        For lngLoop1 = lngCount To 1 Step -1
            If Left(xlBook.Worksheets(lngLoop1).Name, 5) = "Sheet" Then
                xlBook.Worksheets(lngLoop1).Delete
            End If
        Next lngLoop1
        xlBook.Worksheets(1).Delete
        xlApp.Visible = True
    End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - I haven't, no. I don't know much about either. Is this a known complication with DAO?

Comment: Ignore my comment about `ADO`. I dug in further. Instead of using `CopyFromRecordset`, try looping through the rows/fields and placing the cells manually. This approach sucks in ways, but it's worked for me when `CopyFromRecordset` was wonky.

Comment: I reviewed the code above and it looks ok so far. Also ran a quick test to export a table with 3000 records and various field types in Access and Excel 2016. Worked fine within a second. Therefore I suspect that your query might have a flaw (see also answer below re. difference between int and text in queries). You should check with ```rs.recordcount``` that your query retrieved any records (actually, as an alternative you could do that by moving the code for the first row into the if construct).

Comment: Another thought I have is that you might have a table with the various options where rsData is linked to using the record ID (that's what you usually do). Then the condition with "faneblad" would fail.

Answer (score 0):

This is text type.

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_final_output WHERE [" & faneblad & "]=" & "'" & rsLabel(faneblad) & "'"
```

This is int type.

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_final_output WHERE [" & faneblad & "]=" & rsLabel(faneblad)
```

Comment: That's very interesting, the "int type" way was the way I had it originally, but it resulted in an error. I'll have to check once I'm back at work, thanks for the suggestion!